# Two instances despite using concurrent requests and low traffic

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wicket

My Apache Wicket web application uses JDO for its data persistence in GAE/J.

On application start-up, the home page enqueues a task before it is shown (with zero delay to its default ETA). This task causes the construction of a new Wicket web page, in order to construct the JVM's singleton Persistence Manager Factory (PMF) instance for use by the application during its lifetime.

I have set the application to use concurrent requests by adding

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
```

to the application's appengine-web.xml file.

Despite this, after a single request to visit the application's home page, I get two application instances: one created by the home page visit request, and the other created by the execution of the enqueued task (about 6 to 7 seconds later).

I could try to solve this problem by delaying the execution of the enqueued task (by  around 10 seconds, perhaps?), but why should I need to try this when I have enabled concurrent requests? Should the first GAE/J application instance not be able to handle two requests close together without causing a second instance to be brought forth? I presume that I am doing something wrong, but what is it?

I have searched Stack Overflow's set of tags ([google-app-engine] [java]), and the depreciating group "Google App Engine for Java" too, but have found nothing relevant to my question.

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What is your Min Pending Latency setting on the application settings page on your app dashboard?

Comment: The older instance had a latency of around 2.5s. This would be the time to spin up the instance and present the first page to the user. The newer instance had a latency of around 0.5s. All requests after the first seem to be handled by this newer instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the task to use an existing instance, you can set the `X-AppEngine-FailFast` header, which according to the GAE docs:

> This header instructs the Scheduler to immediately fail the request if an existing instance is not available. The Task Queue will retry and back-off until an existing instance becomes available to service the request

It's worth checking out the [Managing Your App's Resource Usage](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/managing-resources.html) document for performance and tuning techniques.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Simon, both for the reference to the documentation and also for the header tip. I have coded the adding of the header to my initialisation tasks. If this does not work, I shall try using TaskOptions.countdownMillis(...) instead.

Comment: According to the latest GAE docs, the X-AppEngine-FailFast header now "specifies that a task running on a backend fails immediately instead of waiting in a pending queue." I am not using back-ends, so this will not help me. Using this header in production confirms this: the task enqueued by the first app instance is often handled by a new, second app instance.